# How to replace dataframe columns having ? symbol with mean value of the column in spark scala?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, replace, mean, mode

Having dataframes with following columns:

| one | two | three | four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ? | Jaun | 3.47 |
| 3 | 164 | Jaun | 3.47 |
| 1 | ? | ? | 2.68 |
| 3 | 164 | Kaul | ? |
| 1 | ? | ? | 2.68 |

Need to replace df columns having '?' with mean and mode according to its datatype.
If the column is of Int type -> need to replace with mean
If the column is of String type -> need to replace with mode

Expected Output:

| one | two | three | four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | **65.6** | Jaun | 3.47 |
| 3 | 164 | Jaun | 3.47 |
| 1 | **65.6** | **Jaun** | 2.68 |
| 3 | 164 | Kaul | **2.46** |
| 1 | **65.6** | **Jaun** | 2.68 |

Comment: mean of what ? mod of what ?

Comment: mean of corresponding dataframe columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will produce the required result, some optimizations might require though.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val inDF = // Read data

  inDF
    .withColumn("two", when('two === "?",
      mean(when('two === "?", 0).otherwise('two)).over()).otherwise('two))
    .withColumn("four", when('four === "?",
      mean(when('four === "?", 0).otherwise('four)).over()).otherwise('four))
    .withColumn("no_occurrence", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("three")))
    .withColumn("max_occurrence", when('three =!= "?", max('no_occurrence).over()).otherwise(0))
    .withColumn("replacement", max(when('no_occurrence === 'max_occurrence, 'three)).over())
    .withColumn("three", when('three === "?", 'replacement).otherwise('three))
    .drop("no_occurrence", "max_occurrence", "replacement")
    .show(false)

    +---+----+-----+----+
    |one|two |three|four|
    +---+----+-----+----+
    |3  |65.6|Jaun |3.47|
    |3  |164 |Jaun |3.47|
    |3  |164 |Kaul |2.46|
    |1  |65.6|Jaun |2.68|
    |1  |65.6|Jaun |2.68|
    +---+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you. but for getting correct mean value, we are replacing initially with 0 and changing that 0's with mean value.. But it may cause already existing 0 values with mean value right?

Comment: Fixed the issue. Edited the post, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks Mohana. can you please explain the no_occurence, max_occurence and replacement part

Comment: To get mean we have inbuilt funtion in spark but not for mode, I used windows functionality to get that.

no_occurences column will have- how many times one particular word is repeteated in a column.
max_occurrence column will have - max count of  no_occurences. I'm marking 0 as a value for these 2 columns for the row with "?".
If we don't mark zero then ? will be considered for calculations. replacement will have which string to replace with ?, will get this by checking 
which row has  no_occurences==max_occurrence.
After each withColumn, you can call show() method and verify these.

Comment: Thank you so much Mohana.. One more optizied way to replace with mode,                    inDF.withColumn("three",when(col("three") === "?",inDF.groupBy(col("three")).count().orderBy(desc("count")).first()(0))    .otherwise(col("three")))

Comment: groupBy approach is also okay. I hope Window functionalities gives better performance, need to run and check both the codes with some data.  And one more thing before doing groupBy you  should filter out "?", otherwise this will also get included while calculating mode. For ex: if we have "?" 3 times "Jaun" 2  times, your code will give "?" as mode

Comment: Yes. Performance wise not sure. Need to check.. Thanks for pointing out that filtering of the symbol

Answer (score 0):

The mode is a bit tricky because SparkSQL doesn't support `mode()` or similar functionality.  But you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(two, two_avg),
       coalesce(three,
                max(case when three_cnt = max_three_cnt then three end) over ()
               ),
       coalesce(four, four_avg)
from (select t.*,
             max(three_cnt) over () as max_three_cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   avg(two) over () as two_avg,
                   count(*) over (partition by three) as three_cnt,
                   avg(four) over () as four_avg
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```